# Regex to find html in between curly brackets in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I'm new to regex and I am having some trouble. I'm trying the get everything between {{#user_data?}} and {{/user_data?}}

```
$content = '
{{#user_data?}}
<span class="hello">
Hello, {{username}}!
</span>
{{/user_data?}}';

$key = 'user_data?';
$regex = '/\{\{#'.$key.'\}\}(.*?)\{\{\/'.$key.'\}\}/';
if (preg_match_all($regex, $content, $matches))
{
print_r($matches);
}
else
echo 'no match found';
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Writing your own template parser? There are so many good ones already...

Comment: You did not escape the `?`. If left as meta character, it will make matching for the `a` optional.`

Comment: @WesleyMurch Yes, I call it: PHP. It's *the* template language per se.

Comment: @DanLee: There are good reasons to use a template parser, one of which is sandboxing allowed code (if you don't want designers accidentally or purposely running `unlink('index.php')` or other such nonsense). Another is language-independent templates (look at Mustache for an extreme example), and of course there are so many more reasons you could write a book  on the subject. People who say "just use PHP" perhaps have not encountered these problems.

Comment: @WesleyMurch Yes there may be good reasons to use a template parser, I agree. But in many cases you buy yourself overhead and some pseudo-language on top, where you could just stick to PHP itself, as it brings great templating features out of the box.

Comment: "Overhead" is negated by one simple word: cache. "pseudo-language" is not necessarily a negative - but I do understand your points (Although personally I find PHP an awkward templating language in comparison to some of the alternatives).

Comment: It always depends on the point of view right; writing a book about that isn't a bad idea at all :). I almost find every template language awkward, can you give me a name of a stylish one?

Comment: In regards to *only* syntax, Smarty can be quite elegant: `{if $var}Hello{/if}` or something like `{widget name="posts" num="5"}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to comments' "not escaping `?` sign", you also need proper modifiers:

```php
$content = <<<STR
{{#user_data?}}
<span class="hello">
Hello, {{username}}!
</span>
{{/user_data?}}
STR;

$key = 'user_data\?';
$regex = '/\{\{#'.$key.'\}\}(.*?)\{\{\/'.$key.'\}\}/sim';
preg_match_all($regex, $content, $matches,PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r($matches);
```

This will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => {{#user_data?}}
<span class="hello">
Hello, {{username}}!
</span>
{{/user_data?}}
            [1] => 
<span class="hello">
Hello, {{username}}!
</span>

        )

)
```

`i` is not necessary, and should be removed if you need case-sensitive template;

`m` may be unnecessary too, according to [PHP Document about PCRE modifiers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php);

`s` is a must, so you can match multiline string with dot.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm going to have to do some more research on modifiers.